# How to get the GPS location from a native app and pass that info to web browser without browser warning?

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to build an app like tinder. but this question is not related only to a dating app. Think any app that use GPS coordinates to locate where are you. Think a traffic app. So instead of creating native apps for android, IOS and windows phone I would like create a one web app by using ASP.net with fully responsive design. What I hope to do is load this web browser behind native apps on these different Operating systems. So yeah I am talking about a hybrid app.

So in tinder they are tracking their GPS location to discover persons who are within some certain Perimeter. So if I use

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

Browser will popup window for ask user's permission to share the location. Also this warning is expire from 24 hours and again this message will popup. this is not what I wanted. So can I write a piece of code for just to get the GPS location from the native app and pass that information to my browser without that warning dialog? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is only possible when you are creating your app with a tool like `Cordova`, `PhoneGap`, ... (there using [a plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/) for Geolocation)

They offer you interfaces to communicate with native APIs, thus skipping the browser dialog.

When only using HTML5 and JS you can't skip that dialog, it's for the user's own protection.